# How do i expand a tree structure with Selenium?

Tags: html, selenium, tree, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a Selenium Projekt at the moment, the Website has a tree structure with several elements.
If you have used the site before all elements that have been expanded in the last session are expanded in the new one as well (should be the coockies).
I know how to expand an element but since they are closed if u use the site for the first time I want to know how I can check if they are expanded or not.
Can anyone of you guys help me out?
I already thought about checking the next element but i hoped that there is a Methode you can use to check this faster.

Tank you very much for youre help
Nanonil

Comment: If you could provide the html it would be helpful. It is likely part of the class of the object i.e "open-tree" vs "closed-tree" or something similar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.